# Python 3 and openpyxl, formatting a list of dates when writing to a file

Tags: python, openpyxl

Please forgive my newbie question.

I have a .xlsx spreadsheet which contains strings, integers and dates. I am reading it by rows using Openpyxl, and then writing it back to a number of text files. The only problem I'm having now is that the dates are in datetime format, and I just want the dates, not the times.

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
numRows = sheet.max_row
destFile = "output.txt"


with open(destFile, "w") as text_file:
    for i in range(1,numRows):
        for cellObj in sheet.rows[i]:
            print(cellObj.value, ',', sep = '', end = '', file=text_file)
        print(file=text_file)
```

Here is the data:

```
04/15/16,Smith,14100
06/19/16,Bertram,22800
08/21/16,Jones,25600
```

And here's what I get:

```
2016-04-15 00:00:00,Smith,14100,
2016-06-19 00:00:00,Bertram,22800,
2016-08-21 00:00:00,Jones,25600,
```

I would like it to look just like it does in the original (the extra commas don't actually bother me). I've found a number of solutions that appear to be aimed toward formatting a date for insertion into another spreadsheet, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work when outputting to a text file.  I have also found similar solutions for printing the current or a calculated date, but not a direct reformat of something that is already stored.

Thanks in advance VERY much!

UPDATE:

Charlie Clark's answer is exactly right.

Here is the version that works: I hard-coded the column with the dates, but it could easily have been a variable.

```
import openpyxl
import datetime

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
numRows = sheet.max_row +1
numCols = sheet.max_column +1
destFile = "output.txt"


with open(destFile, "w") as text_file:
    for i in range(0,numRows-1):
        for cellObj in sheet.rows[i]:
            if cellObj in sheet.columns[0]:
              print(cellObj.value.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), end = ',', file=text_file)
            else:
              print(cellObj.value, ',', sep = '', end = '', file=text_file)
        print(file=text_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.strftime()`is your friend here.

Excel doesn't make a very clear distinction between dates and datetimes, hence openpyxl always converts them to datetimes.

Comment: That was an excellent bump in the right direction. Thank you!